# Android view pager not completely being replaced when replacing fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

My ViewPager's tabs aren't being replaced properly, when I call this method here to replace the view pager fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.content_frame, new NotCharactersFragment())
                           .commit();
```

This code here should replace the Fragment that holds my ViewPager with tabs. When I remove the tabs and just have the fragment that holds my ViewPager, it works, it just messes up when I implement the view pager having tabs as well.

How can I make it so that when I replace the fragment that holds the view pager, it will completely remove everything within the view pager?

here's what the view pager looks like:

[image]

Here's what happens when I navigate from the view pager using my sliding menu:

[image]

The tabs continue on from the view pager, which I don't want.

Here's the view pagers code:

```
public class CharactersFragment extends Fragment {

// Declare Variables
ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;
private ActionBar actionbar;

String[] rank;
String[] country;
String[] population;
int[] flag;
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater Inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.characters, container, false);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // show the given tab



        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // hide the given tab
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }







    // Generate sample data
    rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

    country = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States",
            "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh",
            "Russia", "Japan" };

    population = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422",
            "315,761,000", "237,641,326", "193,946,886", "182,912,000",
            "170,901,000", "152,518,015", "143,369,806", "127,360,000" };

    flag = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india,
            R.drawable.unitedstates, R.drawable.indonesia,
            R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.nigeria,
            R.drawable.bangladesh, R.drawable.russia, R.drawable.japan };

    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), rank, country,
            population, flag);

    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
 }
}
```

View pagers XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: addview pager pagechange listener and change the tab position from there

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, my whole view pager isn't being replaced when I replace the view pagers fragment.